# Why is "and" operator not working in my python program?

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, time, module

The following is my code:

```
import greettime as gt

if int(gt.now.strftime("%H")) < 12:
    print("Good Morning, Rudra!")
elif int(gt.now.strftime("%H")) >= 12 and int(gt.now.strftime("%H")) < 17:
    print("Good Afternoon, Rudra!")
elif int(gt.now.strftime("%H")) >= 17 and int(gt.now.strftime("%H")) < 0:
    print("Good Evening, Rudra!")

print(int(gt.now.strftime("%H")))
```

and the file named greettime is:

```
import datetime as dt
now = dt.datetime.now()
```

This code is not producing any output.It is producing output if the "and" part is commented out. What is the error here? I am a student and learning python therefore asking for pardon if there is a presence of any simple silly mistake

Comment: Can you provide the output?

Comment: Your second `elif` will never be true because a number can't be greater than or equal to 17 AND less than or equal to 0. So commenting that `and` out is the right thing to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code compares the time so that it's...

```
* less than 12
* greater than-equal to 12 and less then 17
* greater than-equal to 17 and less than 0
```

That last condition doesn't work because how is a number going to be greater than 17 and also less than 0? It doesn't work, and Python `datetime` also only supports hours from `0..23`.

If you just to print `Good Morning` if it's midnight - noon, then `Good Afternoon` from noon to 5 PM, and then `Good Evening` otherwise, you can just do this and scrap the final comparison cases and replace it with a bare `else`, because you've already covered morning and afternoon hours.

```
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()

if now.hour < 12:
    print("Good Morning, Rudra!")
elif now.hour >= 12 and now.hour < 17:
    print("Good Afternoon, Rudra!")
else:
    print("Good Evening, Rudra!")

print(now.hour)
```

You'll also notice I got rid of your `strftime` conversions because you [can access the `hour` property on `datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.hour) objects directly.

Answer (score 0):

First, I advise you to store your value in a variable:

```
t = int(gt.now.strftime("%H"))
```

This way, you won't have to recompute a value multiple times, and probably different values each time. (Pedantically, if executed at border times, it could even make for a situation where none of the `if`s will be executable.)

Then your logic would be more readable:

```
if t < 12:
    print("Good Morning, Rudra!")
elif t >= 12 and t < 17:
    print("Good Afternoon, Rudra!")
elif t >= 17 and t < 0:
    print("Good Evening, Rudra!")
```

The last conditions attached by `and` would never be true together. You probably meant before midnight by `t < 0`, but it doesn't make sense here. Leave it out so that your if conditions will be both disjoint and inclusive.